# Express Request .query.xyz as string | string[]

Tags: typescript, express, request

I am trying to assign a type to my variable, that gets its value from express' Request query.  The req.query is of type "QueryString.ParsedQs" 
and for example req.query.accountId is of type "string | QueryString.ParsedQs | string[] | QueryString.ParsedQs[]"

How could i extract the value from req.query.accountId to always be of type string?

Example code:

```
import { Request, Response } from "@feathersjs/express";
class Xyz {
    public myMethod( req: Request, res: Response ){
        const accountId =req.query.accountId;/* type is "string | QueryString.ParsedQs | string[] | QueryString.ParsedQs[]"*/
    }
}
```

Comment: `req.query.accountId as string`?

Comment: yes, i would like to passt the accountId to a function that only accepts a string. Just by saying that its "as string", will it make it a string?

Comment: ...and that's how. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions

Comment: Hm, i mean it should work as long as it is not a ParsedQs, which i am not sure when that happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either check whether a ‛string‛ was passes:

```
if (typeof accounId === 'string')  {
  // do stuff
}
```

Or convert it (forcefully, i would not recommend) it to a string:

```
accountId = String(req.query.accountId);
// Or shorter
accountId = '' + req.query.accountId;
```

If though it was not a string before conversion you will end up with something like ‛[Object array]‛